# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity (Why is my ground truth mask not binary?)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, image-segmentation

I am new to image segmentation and using a model from HuggingFace. I've been trying to use SAM model on a custom data, following this tutorial: https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/SAM/

I am supposed to get an array of 1’s and 0’s when I convert the mask image (which is a tiff image)  into numpy array. But when I check the unique values of ground_truth_seg, it has all sorts of numbers from 0 to 255.  I don’t get what I am missing here.

I think this is what’s causing me getting this ValueError during training phase which seems to be coming from data loader : `“ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity”`

To give more information about the dataset;
The dataset contains 780 breast ultrasound images(PNG format). The data was collected among 600 female patients in ages between 25 and 75 years old in 2018. The dataset has 3 labels:
0 - Benign
1 - Malignant
2 - Normal
Each image also has an associated masked ground truth image. The dataset I am using is from Kaggle, Breast Ultrasound Images Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aryashah2k/breast-ultrasound-images-dataset

This is how I read data:

```
def num (image) :
    val = 0
    for i in range(len(image)) :
        if image[i] == '(' :
            while True :
                i += 1
                if image[i] == ')' :
                    break
                val = (val*10) + int(image[i])
            break
    return val


label2id = dict({
    'benign': 0,
    'malignant': 1,
    'normal': 2
})

id2label = {
    0: 'benign',
    1: 'malignant',
    2: 'normal'
}


# separate the images into masked and unmasked
masked_images = glob.glob("/content/breast-ultrasound-images-dataset/*/*/*_mask*")
non_masked_images = [file for file in glob.glob(os.path.join("/content/breast-ultrasound-images-dataset/*/*", '*')) if 'mask' not in file]

id_list = []
img_list = []
mask_list = []
label_list = []

non_masked_images.sort()
masked_images.sort()

count = len(non_masked_images)
i = 0

while i < count:
    img = non_masked_images[i]
    image_name = img.split('/')[-1].split(')')[0] + ')'
    # ID
    id = str(image_name[0]) + str(num(image_name))
    id_list.append(id)
    # Label
    label = img.split('/')[-2]
    label_list.append(label2id[label])
    # Image
    image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),(256,256))
    img_list.append(Image.fromarray(image))
    # Mask
    r = re.compile(r".*"+re.escape(image_name)) # look for mask
    masks = list(filter(r.match, masked_images))
    mask = None
    for m in masks:
      if mask is None:
        mask = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(m),(256,256))
      else:
        extr_mask = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(m),(256,256))
        mask = cv2.resize(cv2.bitwise_or(mask, extr_mask),(256,256))
    mask_list.append((Image.fromarray(mask)).convert('I'))

    i += 1
```

Here is how I load the data into HuggingFace dataset:

```
from datasets import Dataset, Image

def create_dataset(images, labels):
    dataset = Dataset.from_dict({"image": images,
                                "label": labels})
    dataset = dataset.cast_column("image", Image())
    dataset = dataset.cast_column("label", Image())

    return dataset


dataset = create_dataset(images = img_list, labels = mask_list)
```

This is the result I get from converting the image into numpy array:

[image]

And this is what I'm supposed to get (from the tutorial notebook):

[image]

Here is my notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lJav6_1r9pxf2uMvo5VBi9GoTtIVBldr?usp=sharing

Comment: You could try to load the images via cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED

Comment: About your problem you need to cover the "normal" cases where the ground truth labels are all 0. `np.where` returns a empty list this empty list causes your error in `np.min([])`.

Comment: `tqdm` (what ever that is?) apparently doesn't like the size of its input.  But the connection between that input and the rest of your code is unclear.  If you suspect the problem is with the `unique` or something like that, then show us information about the problem arrays or lists.  The fine print of the error message and traceback is nearly useless (and hard to read)!

Comment: @Daraan, thank you! cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED didn't help with the ground truth mask problem but I filtered out the "normal" cases and it got over the "zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity" error and started training! I guess the error message wasn't because of the mask not being binary, but the question remains as to why I can't get a binary result from the mask.